# C# Process doesn't open in a new window

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exeDirectory);

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = exe;

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

var process = Process.Start(psi);
```

Unfortunately, it's not opened in a new window :( What should I change? I need to leave `UseShellExecute` as `false`.

Comment: Console application?

Comment: What, specifically, constrains you to keeping `UseShellExecute` as `false`?

Comment: Console applications don't run in windows. What you consider a window is actually the *console terminal* that connects to the process Standard IO streams.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so how can I see this console?

Comment: People already answered that. The problems you mention seem to be due to misconceptions and using the wrong code, eg `SetCurrentDirectory` only affects the current process, not child processes. That's what `psi.WorkingDirectory` is for. What are you trying to do? Why do you *want* a window?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must set this property to true. `psi.UseShellExecute = true`;

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = exe;

psi.UseShellExecute = true; //false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

var process = Process.Start(psi);
```

**ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute**

`true` if the shell should be used when starting the process; false if the process should be created directly from the executable file. The default is true on .NET Framework apps and false on .NET Core apps. [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-7.0)

Comment: With `UseShellExecute` I'm not able to use `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`. What is the alternative?

Comment: Echo the content you read from `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` to the console?

Comment: What is more, I can't set CurrentDirectory path with `psi.UseShellExecute` set to true - I've got an error that Process object must have this property to false to use environment variables.

Comment: @Ugus If  `ShellExecute` is used to start the process you lose access to the input and output streams.  Therefore, you cannot call `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: `I can't set CurrentDirectory path` you can. That will affect only the *current* application though, not the new one you start. The `Shell` in `UseShellExecute` is Windows Explorer, which provides the window

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the application which I want to run is a Console Application which at some point extract the current working directory path and based on this path it tries to laod some files. When I running this exe file from my c# script (now with `useShellExecute` set to true), It fails due to this incorrect working directory path

Comment: Set the correct working directory with `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`. Better yet, pass the *full* paths to the process as arguments instead of depending on relative paths

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos great, now it works! I just wondering what is now the easiest way to extract the output from my application since now `psiRedirectStandardOutput` is set to `false`?

Comment: Set redirect to `true` and echo the output to the console yourself from the data you get using `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`?